# Returning Text Nodes

Tags: jquery, dom, nodes, textnode

I'm using this line of code:

```
$("#middle_child").contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;}).text();
```

For now, I'm just placing this in a console.log(). I'm using Chrome for testing & value returns as an empty string, but the value should return "Middle Child".

This is the HTML:

```
<div id='parent'>
  Parent
  <div id='oldest_child'>
    Oldest Child
    <div id='middle_child'>
      Middle Child
        <div id='youngest_child'>
          Youngest Child
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id='lone'>Lonely Div</div>
```

**EDIT**: I tried making a jsfiddle & that did provide me with some potential insight. In the fiddle I selected jQuery 1.6.4 & it worked just fine. The version of jQuery I'm running on my site is 1.6.2. Does anyone know if that could be part (if not all) of my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue.

First off, I lied, I'm using jQuery Version 1.9.1 for some reason it shows up as 1.6.2 in the link, but the file is 1.9.1.

Now, my issue: I forgot to wrap my script inside of a $(document).ready().

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried storing the .text value into a variable and logging it? Not sure where your issue is coming in. Have a look at this JSFiddle, it uses the same code you posted. Clicking the button will replace the text inside #lone with the text from #middle_child.

http://jsfiddle.net/m5xPd/

```
 var data = $("#middle_child").contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
 }).text();

 $('#button').click(function(){
     $('#lone').empty().append(data);
 });
```

Comment: It seems to work just fine in JSFiddle, but it doesn't work on my site. The best theory I have for that is that my site is using jQuery 1.6.2 & the closest JSFiddle has to that is 1.6.4.
Still, I would expect that I would receive an error of some kind, as opposed to an empty string being returned.
Here's the JSFiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/6q5Lx/

Comment: Can you try replacing your version of jQuery with a newer one and see if the issue corrects itself? Is there a reason you're stuck on 1.6.2?

Comment: That's not up to me to do, however I found the issue. I'll post it in a moment.